# I am failing to integrate Firebase into my App

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am failing to integrate Firebase into my App - Receiving the following errors:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-beta1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-41
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:44 to override.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **override** the support library to remove the error by adding the support library in your dependencies block. You need to add the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
   //... Your other dependencies

   implementation "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
}
```

Comment: @danielPossible: Great that it help you! If your problem solved by this answer, please mark as an accepted answer ;)